# getElementsByTagName('img').length logs out to 0

Tags: javascript

I have read multiple posts on this, but still don't understand why document.getElemenstsByTagName('img').length prints out '0' but when you console log it shows you the right length.

To further explain my problem, part of my HTML looks like this

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="slider">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i am dynamically adding the  elements as children to the #slider element.

In my javascript i have an object

```
var manualSlide = {
 imageLength: document.getElementsByTagName('img').length,
//other properties 
};
```

Why does the property 'imageLength' gets assigned '0' instead of the actual length?

Edit:

Here is my entire script

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('data.json',function(data){
        $.each(data.images, function(key){
            setImages(data.images[key]);
        });
    });

    function setImages(obj){
        var imgTag = '';
        imgTag += "<img src='" + obj.Url + "' style='width:800px;height:400px' alt ='"+ obj.Title +"' name='pics'/>";
        $('#slider').append(imgTag);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var slide = getManualSlide();

        document.getElementsByClassName('left').onclick = function(){
            slide.previousImg();
        };

        document.getElementsByClassName('right')[0].onclick = function(){
            slide.nextImg();
        };

        function getManualSlide(){

            var manualSlide = {
                imageNum : 1,
                imageLength: document.getElementsByTagName('img').length,
                image: document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
                previousImg: function(){
                    if(this.imageNum > 1){
                        this.imageNum --;
                    }
                    else{
                        this.imageNum = this.imageLength;
                    }

                    document.pics.src = this.image[this.imageLength - 1];
                },
                nextImg: function(){
                    if(this.imageNum > this.imageNum){
                        this.imageNum ++;
                    }
                    else{
                        this.imageNum = 1;
                    }

                    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('img').length);
                    console.log(this.imageLength);
                    document.pics.src = this.image[this.imageLength - 1];
                }
            };

            return manualSlide;

        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is probably in a `<script>` tag in the `<head>`, which appears **before** all the `<img>` tags in the `<body>`. The code in `<script>` tags is evaluated immediately, before the browser proceeds to parse subsequent parts of the page.

Comment: Yup. Read the comment section: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067682/drag-and-drop-code-does-not-work-on-chrome#comment46371142_29067682

Comment: if you are using jQuery you could also use $("img").length instead of document.getElementsByTagName('img').length

Answer (score 2):

It's all about where or when your code gets executed.

You have to make sure your code gets executed after the image tags are parsed (added to the DOM tree).
To do that you could put your code either behind the img-tags in the body or you wait for the document to be loaded:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
     imageLength = document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;
     console.log(imageLength);
  });
</script>
```

You can read more about this event [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

If you are using jQuery you could also use

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code goes here */ });
```

which does exactly the same.

Comment: i did try with $document.ready{....} it still reads out as 0 instead of the actual length

Comment: also doesn't $document.ready(){..} execute before all the other object and images are parsed

Comment: It's $(document).ready(function(){...}) instead of $document.ready{...}

Comment: It should get executed when the DOM is loaded (including your image tags). However it does not mean the images have been loaded (That whats the 'load' event is for $(window).load(function(){...}); )

Answer (score 0):

Because the object was created when no img tags were in the document. The object data will not update with the document. If you want this behavior you should use events.

Instead create a function to return an updated object. See below:

```
function getManualSlide()
{
    var imgLen = document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;
    var manualSlide = {
     imageLength: imgLen
    };    

    return manualSlide;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2akca0dg/2/